# SceneKit – material's colorBufferWriteMask

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm working with SceneKit (swift) and found `colorBufferWriteMask` parameter that working with SCNMaterial. But it's still working with iOS11+.

So, have anyone know a parameter like `colorBufferWriteMask` that working with iOS9+?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After research about scenekit, i found a solution. The first, i create a SCNNode (A) that is setting with opacity = 0.000001 and renderingOrder = -1. The second, i create other SCNNode (B) that setting with renderingOrder = 100 and add A.

So, right now, Part of B will be hidden, and this is okie like colorBufferWriteMask.

Thanks.